# how to get the required data from the list by the cycle and then use them

Tags: python, list

```
spisok = ['Ivan Ivanov, [20.08.21]', 'Algoritm 6', 'action: take a walk in the woods', 'Ivan Ivanov, [20.08.21]', 'Algoritm 7', 'action: dig']
full_data = []
data = {}
for word in spisok:                  
    if 'Ivan Ivanov' in word:       
        data['data'] = word      
    if 'Algoritm' in word:
        data['Algoritm'] = word       
    if 'action' in word:
        data['action'] = word           
        full_data.append(data)

print (full_data)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v3nIF.png)

list very big, this is an example

output:
[{'data': 'Ivan Ivanov, [20.08.21]', 'Algoritm': 'Algoritm 7', 'action': 'action: dig'}, {'data': 'Ivan Ivanov, [20.08.21]', 'Algoritm': 'Algoritm 7', 'action': 'action: dig'}]

but me need :
[{'data': 'Ivan Ivanov, [20.08.21]', 'Algoritm': 'Algoritm 6', 'action': 'take a walk in the woods'}, {'data': 'Ivan Ivanov, [20.08.21]', 'Algoritm': 'Algoritm 7', 'action': 'action: dig'}]

Comment: Your question is completely unintelligible.  Format python code properly.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

```
import numpy as np
spisok = ['Ivan Ivanov, [20.08.21]', 'Algoritm 6', 'action: take a walk in the woods', 'Ivan Ivanov, [20.08.21]', 'Algoritm 7', 'action: dig']

array = np.array(spisok)
one = np.arange(0, len(spisok), 3)
two = np.arange(1, len(spisok), 3)
three = np.arange(2, len(spisok), 3)
full_data = [{'data': x, 'Algoritm': y, 'action': z} for x, y, z in zip(array[one], array[two], array[three])]
print(full_data)
```

OUT:

```
[{'data': 'Ivan Ivanov, [20.08.21]', 'Algoritm': 'Algoritm 6', 'action': 'action: take a walk in the woods'}, {'data': 'Ivan Ivanov, [20.08.21]', 'Algoritm': 'Algoritm 7', 'action': 'action: dig'}]
```

Comment: list very big, this is an example

Comment: Edited to improve performance. I think this should be fairly fast - zip is an iterator in python and converting from list to numpy arrays will be speed things up a lot too.

Comment: I mean, there's a lot of data to look for, about 50 if I write 
if 'Ivan Ivanov' in word:       
        data['data'] = word      
    if 'Algoritm' in word:
        data['Algoritm'] = word       
    if 'action' in word:
        data['action'] = word 
its very fast